# Manual Commands Behind Programs Like nmap or Aircrack

Tags: linux

How do I go about figuring out the manual commands being run by things like nmap and aircrack? In other words, I want to figure out exactly what commands are being run in the background that we can't see, the commands that are being automated by these programs information. A google search of "manually portscan without nmap" only leads to links about automating nmap scans.

So for example, if I ran the command: nmap -sS 192.168.1.*, what is actually happening behind the scenes? How would I do the same thing manually? Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about documentation rather than a programming problem.

Answer (score 4):

For open source tools like nmap, your best bet is to download the source code yourself,
then step through it (conceptually, or with the aid of a debugger) to see exactly what the program is doing.  If you're lucky, there will be helpful comments in the source.

If you don't have access to the source code, you can use system call tracing tools
(for example, [strace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) on Linux), which can give you some hints about what is going on "under the hood" (e.g. which files or sockets are being opened).

Answer (score 3):

More likely these are issuing operating system calls, not things easily invoked manually.

Comment: The reason I ask is because I always hear people on certain forums talk about how you shouldn't be a skiddie and use automated tools until you understand how they work and how to do the same things without them. How does someone crack a WPA key without using Aircrack or similar?

Comment: You don't want me to answer that question. You REALLY don't want me to answer that question. You won't like me if I answer that question.

The polite answer is that they write code.

Comment: I see the problem here. Sorry, didn't mean to ask "How to crack WPA key without aircrack." I was just trying to get an idea of what that even means. What is actually happening when you ,for example, discover nearby networks by running airmon? I guess the more appropriate question would be how do I discover this information?

Comment: What's happening, at an abstract level, is that you're asking the network adapter to listen for a while and gather a list of all the networks which have sent out packets during that period. (The network's name is part of the packet header.)

As to which system call is issued in order to do that... I haven't had reason to do it, but websearching "linux wifi configuration api" should find a description of what operations are supported and might find a tutorial.